# Disable memory scrambling

Tags: memory

Is it possible to disable memory scrambling for RAM?
Can you change what kind of algorithm is used?
Can you check from inside the OS which is using the memory if/what scrambling is in use?
Do devices with soldered RAM or smartphones use memory scrambling?

Comment: This question could really benefit from some additional information. "Can you check from inside the system what is in use?" - inside which system?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to disable memory scrambling for RAM?

I've [read](https://community.intel.com/t5/Processors/memory-scrambler/td-p/393672) from an Intel community manager that you cannot disable the memory scrambler, as it's enabled by design:

> Is it possible to turn on/off the scrambler function on my machine by myself? No. It is not possible as it is enabled by design.

> Can you change what kind of algorithm is used?

It depends on your hardware. Some ASUS motherboards allows you to use either ASUS or Intel algorithm.

> Can you check from inside the OS which is using the memory if/what scrambling is in use?

There's no way to do that. Memory Scrambling is done transparently and on hardware (on the memory controller chip), so the OS don't even have any means to probe that. It's well outside its domain.

> Do devices with soldered RAM or smartphones use memory scrambling?

Probably. If the processor on the device supports memory scrambling, the device manufacturer can use it if they want to. Memory scrambling is not used only for security, but for reducing crosstalk on the bus, so devices with fast memory access would benefit from it.

According to the [datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/atom-processor-s1200-datasheet-vol-1.pdf), security is the third objective. Primary objectives are reduce power supply noise, and improve signal integrity. That could be useful on smartphones too.

Comment: All devices with DDR3 or newer use memory scrambling. It's not secure at all, since you can break it trivially with the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm. You may want to look at how Coreboot handles the scramble seed, which should show you that it _is_ possible to disable, albeit only with a custom BIOS.